# Is "would the first thing you would do" correct?

Tags: grammar

I am not sure if this is a warranted feeling, but I feel like using "would" twice sounds kind of ungrammatical. Also, I looked at the n-gram for this and I barely get any result.

Here's the sentence I was trying to write:

> If you were the President, would the first thing you would do be
>   trying to enact Medicare for all?

Like I said, I feel it's weird to have two would, would you replace the second would with something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a beautiful sentence but there's nothing ungrammatical or confusing about it.

You could contract the second "would" to ease the problem slightly:

> If you were the President, would the first thing **you'd** do be trying to enact Medicare for all?

Or perhaps

> If you were the President, would the first thing **you'd try to do** be Medicare for all?